# How to choose between date in Google Sheet table and given date with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, compare

I am trying to generate PDFs for each row of a particular table... If you look at createPDF(), I'm having some difficulty handling the startingDate argument:

- I want to compare the date in my table to the first day of the
  current month;
- If the date in my table is more recent, then I'll use
  it as my startingDate argument, otherwise I want to use the first day of the current month.

I'm guessing maybe I should declare a `let startingDate[]` and write into it, but I can't seem to make it work.

Would you guys be so kind as to help me?
THANK YOU! ^_^

```
function createBulkPDFs(){
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1CEJjt50pwNQpK_9tefzpNg5fzie8BeswZV3B4cecpPs");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1keBnLhrMWjGokTOFdi2o25tjkTKjrKbO");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("18N2DyrBRNggXle9Pfdi3wbn0NTcdgt93");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Récupération du lead")

  const data = currentSheet.getRange(2,1,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,33).getDisplayValues();

  const date = new Date();
  const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toLocaleString("fr-FR").slice(0,10);
  
  let errors = [];
  data.forEach(row => {
    try{
      createPDF(row[2],row[3],row[10],row[11],
      /* find startingDate 
      IF row[4] is newer than firstDayOfMonth select row[4] as startingDate
      ELSE select firstDayOfMonth as startingDate
      */
      row[2] + " " + row[3],docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
      errors.push([""]);
    } catch(err){
      errors.push(["Failed"]);
    }   
  });

  currentSheet.getRange(2,32,currentSheet.getLastRow()-1,1).setValues(errors);

}

function createPDF(firstName,lasttName,formation,client,startingDate,pdfName,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {
  
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{PRENOM}", firstName);
  body.replaceText("{NOM}", lasttName);
  body.replaceText("{FORMATION}", formation);
  body.replaceText("{CLIENT}", client);
  body.replaceText("{DEBUT}", debut);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);

}
```

Here's a look at my table:

| MainID | Task ID | LastName | FirstName | Start Date | Due Date | Comment | Progress | Statut | URL Session | Formation | Client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b093eed1-d55c-41f1-9999-644b6af411bb | 120239E15 | DOE | John | 2022-05-02 0:00:00 | 2023-01-07 12:00:00 | Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum | Ok | Lorem ipsum | BBB |  |
| b093eed1-d55c-41f1-9999-644b6af511cc | 120239Z00 | SMITH | Anna | 2022-06-02 0:00:00 | 2023-08-09 12:00:00 | Lorem ipsum | Lorem ipsum | Pending | Lorem ipsum | CCC |  |

Comment: Have you tried using the conditional statement "startingDate > firstDayOfMonth" (based on your code)? It should return "true" if the startingDate from your table is more recent than the first day of the month. On the other hand, may I ask for the purpose of the variable debut in your createPDF() function? When I removed the line with "debut", the createPDF() worked just fine. It even changed the text within the PDF created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this

I modified your script by removing the `try-catch` statements and then replaced it with a `for` loop so that each row in your spreadsheet would be checked one by one. In addition, I have listed the important variables inside the `for` loop to lessen confusion.

As for the comparison of dates, I used `startingDate >= firstDayOfMonth` since it returns true when `startingDate` is more recent than `firstDayOfMonth`.

On the other hand, your `createPDF()` function works just fine. I just modified the "debut" part so that it links the recent date.

```
function createBulkPDFs(){
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("doc file ID");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("temp folder ID");
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("pdf folder ID");
  const currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Récupération du lead")

  const date = new Date();
  const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1).toLocaleString("fr-FR").slice(0,10);
  for(i=2; i<=currentSheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var firstName = currentSheet.getRange(i,4,1,1).getValues();
    var lasttName = currentSheet.getRange(i,3,1,1).getValues();
    var formation = currentSheet.getRange(i,11,1,1).getValues();
    var client = currentSheet.getRange(i,12,1,1).getValues();
    var startingDate = currentSheet.getRange(i,5,1,1).getValues();
    var debut = (startingDate >= firstDayOfMonth) ? startingDate : firstDayOfMonth;
    createPDF(firstName, lasttName, formation, client, debut, firstName + " " + lasttName, docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder);
  }
}

function createPDF(firstName,lasttName,formation,client,startingDate,pdfName,docFile,tempFolder,pdfFolder) {
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{PRENOM}", firstName);
  body.replaceText("{NOM}", lasttName);
  body.replaceText("{FORMATION}", formation);
  body.replaceText("{CLIENT}", client);
  body.replaceText("{DEBUT}", startingDate);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
  tempFolder.removeFile(tempFile);
}
```

### Output

As for the output, I just assumed that `debut = startingDate`. The output should look like this:

[image: pdf created]

The pdf folder has the created PDFs. And since you did not provide a copy of the doc file, I merely made a test case format:

[image: test case]

Which should be converted to the one below once the script is done running:

[image: to this]